# SQL query retorna valor duplicados e com erro

Tags: sql

Tenho a seguinte query mas está a retornar resultados duplicados e errados. No Arthur deveria aparecer 0 e não 30.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: por favor, coloque o código aqui e não printscreen.

Comment: Sua query está sem nenhum Where?...

Comment: você não tem nenhuma condição nos joins

Answer (score 1):

Ja cheguei a conclusão de como faz:

```
SELECT Player_name, Subscription_id,Date_subscription,Amount_paid,Attendance_id,Training_date
FROM PLAYER p,SUBSCRIPTION s, Attendance a
WHERE p.SUBSCRIPTION_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = s.SUBSCRIPTION_ID and a.PLAYER_PLAYER_ID = p.PLAYER_ID;
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, Diana; faltava estabelecer as junções. O Thiago e o Rovann já haviam _cantado a pedra_.  // Sugestão: estabeleça as junções usando a cláusula ON. Deixe para a cláusula WHERE somente os filtros. Isto facilita a compreensão e manutenção posterior.